# The broker does not support INCREMENTAL_ALTER_CONFIGS

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, kafka-topic

When trying to alter a docker container kafka topic retention.ms (in order to purge it) I am encountering this error:

> Error while executing config command with args '--bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --entity-type topics --alter --entity-name
> history.data_state_change --add-config retention.ms=1000'
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnsupportedVersionException: The broker
> does not support INCREMENTAL_ALTER_CONFIGS
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:396)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2096)
> at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:180)
> at kafka.admin.ConfigCommand$.alterConfig(ConfigCommand.scala:360)
> at kafka.admin.ConfigCommand$.processCommand(ConfigCommand.scala:327)
> at kafka.admin.ConfigCommand$.main(ConfigCommand.scala:98)
> at kafka.admin.ConfigCommand.main(ConfigCommand.scala)
> Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnsupportedVersionException: The broker
> does not support INCREMENTAL_ALTER_CONFIGS

The command I am running is:

> kafka-configs --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --entity-type topics --alter --entity-name history.data_state_change --add-config retention.ms=1000

I am not sure what is this `INCREMENTAL_ALTER_CONFIGS` and how do I add it, can someone share some wisdom here?

Comment: Error is self-explanatory. You should show what docker image you're running; you don't "add" it; you upgrade the broker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As advised by OneCricketeer - I changed my Kafka image from `IMAGE_KAFKA := wurstmeister/kafka:2.11-2.0.0` to `IMAGE_KAFKA := wurstmeister/kafka:2.13-2.7.1` which did the trick.